# Angular 2 Shows "Not Found" when routing to /test

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular development and i try to add routing to my application but it working fine for some of the routes but not working for some routes i don't know what's wrong in my route coding example when i route `/events` it working when i route `events/:id` it also working but when i route `/test` this is not working.

Here is my files and code please give me suggesting

app-component.js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'event-app',
    template: `
        <navbar></navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `})
export class EventAppComponent{ }
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    template: `<h1>Hello from testing component</h1>`
})
export class TestComponent{ }
```

routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { EventListComponent } from './events/events-list.component'
import { EventDetailComponent } from './events/event-details/event-detail.component'
import { CreateEventComponent } from './events/event-create.component'
import { Error404Component } from './error/404.component'
import { EventRouteActivator } from './events/events-route.activator.service'
import { EventsListResolverService } from './events/events-list.resolver.service'
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component'

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'events/new', component: CreateEventComponent },
    { path: '404', component: Error404Component },
    { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
    { path: 'events', component: EventListComponent, resolve: {events: EventsListResolverService} },
    { path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailComponent, 
        canActivate:[EventRouteActivator] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/events', pathMatch: 'full' },
]
```

app-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { EventAppComponent } from './app.component'
import { EventListComponent } from './events/events-list.component'
import { EventListThumbnailComponent } from './events/events-list.thumbnail.component'
import { EventDetailComponent } from './events/event-details/event-detail.component'
import { NavbarComponent } from './nav/navbar.component'
import { EventService } from './events/events-service'
import { ToastrService } from './common/toastr.service'
import { CreateEventComponent } from './events/event-create.component'
import { Error404Component } from './error/404.component'
import { EventRouteActivator } from './events/events-route.activator.service'
import { EventsListResolverService } from './events/events-list.resolver.service'
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component'
import { AppRoutes } from './routs'

@NgModule({

    imports : [ 
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes,
            { enableTracing: true })
    ],
    declarations: [
        EventAppComponent,
        EventListComponent,
        EventListThumbnailComponent,
        EventDetailComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        CreateEventComponent,
        Error404Component,
        TestComponent
    ],
    providers: [ 
        EventService,
        ToastrService,
        EventRouteActivator,
        EventsListResolverService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ EventAppComponent ]

})
export class AppModule{ }
```

Comment: Take a look on what you declared on `canActivate` guards, if it's added somewhere you should give access for the children you want to be active.

Answer (score 2):

I have created [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MtKvU3TNzOp8KPpC0zbM?p=preview) with working navigation to the test module. The problem can be that in navigation was used relational path instead of absolute. For better understanding check [Angular routing documentation](http://angular%20routing%20documentation).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button routerLink="/test">Navigate to test</button>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes,
            { enableTracing: true }) ],
  declarations: [ App, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```